# Are there "shortcuts" in the comments, or is this unintentional?

Tags: support, comments, magic-links

I was just editing one of my comments and I edited my message to contain the text `[edit]`.

Yes, I know there's a pencil to indicate that a comment has been edited). What I noticed however is that this resulted in a link to edit the post's contents (so not the actual comment). After that I did some more digging and there is another message that also creates a link: `[answer]` - this links to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

This seems like a useful shortcut (to the How to Answer page) for telling people who are new to the site or who are posting low quality answers.

My question is: is this intentional, and if so, what other "shortcuts" are there I can use? Is there a list somewhere?

Demonstration in the comments of this post.

Comment: Demonstration: [edit] [answer]

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments

Comment: Full functionality at: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: Click the "Help" link to the right of the comment box, then click the "Learn more..." in the help text

Comment: Yes, there are shortcuts, click the 'help' link next to the comment box, then the "Learn more...' link: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: Thanks guys, that covers it. My bad for not checking the comment formatting documentation, to be fairy I didn't even know it existed (the help text is almost not visible on my screen).

Comment: Related: everything under the [meta-tag:magic-links] tag. And yes, I used a magic link shortcut for that, `[meta-tag:magic-links]`.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there are shortcuts. You can find a list of them in *[Markdown help, Comment formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)*.

There is also a *[canonical list on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000)*.

Comment: The [canonical list is on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000) (from [Quick reference links to important SO pages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400525))