# Quick reference links to important SO pages

Tags: discussion, comments, magic-links

While commenting on questions by new users on Stack Overflow, it's often useful to link some of the important pages from the help center. Pages such as -

- [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [Minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Are there shortcuts for quick references to these articles in the comment section?

Example - I know that the helpcenter page for a minimum reproducible example can be linked just by `[mre]` in the comments. Are there other such pages with quick references?

Comment: get a big screen and enable the bookmarks, over time there come a lot of links togehther

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/250916) is a list of working "magic links" on Meta SE.

Comment: Can we have one for "What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it"?

Comment: it would be great if we can have more such "magic links" for SO!

Comment: All of this information ought to be **much, much** more discoverable. I flail around trying to remember how on Earth I'm intended to look it up or remember it, **every time**.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For the first one, How to ask a good question, you can simply do `[ask]`. There is also `[tour]` for the site tour, and `[help]` for the help center.

If you want them to edit their question, you can do `[edit]`.

And `[mre]` leads to the Minimum Reproducible Example only on the main site. It doesn't work on meta, as stated in the comments.

Here are some more:

- `[meta]` to go to the meta site of a network (that is only if it exists: Some SE networks don't have a meta or if it ***is*** the meta site).
- `[main]` leads to the main site, and does nothing if the site ***is already*** the main site.
- `[chat]` leads to the chat for the network.
- `[mcve]` or `[reprex]` or `[example]` or `[repro]` are all alternatives to `[mre]`
- `[so]` leads to Stack Overflow
- `[su]` leads to Super User
- `[a51]` leads to Area 51
- `[answer]` links to the [How to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.

[Here is the full list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000)

Comment: [xxx.SE] works nicely. Example [ stats.SE ] = [stats.SE]

Comment: @Trilarion [stats.SE] works! I'll [edit] my post.

Comment: @Trilarion of course that relies on knowing the shorthand community name. I believe it's based off the URL, so **math**.stackexchange.com is `[math.se]`

Comment: Are we looking to replicate the list on MSE here? If you want to compile a list, you could also look at the other questions tagged [meta-tag:magic-links] here on MSO.

Comment: Comment template: Find out [ask]. Then take the [tour] and read [help]. Try [edit]ing.