# Should I use /help/mcve to refer to the minimal, reproducible example page?

Tags: discussion, minimal-reproducible-example

Recently Stack Overflow has implemented the "Minimal, Reproducible Example" page in place of the earlier "Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example" page. However, the link to the old page (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) does redirect to the new page. But should I continue to use this link to refer to the new page, or is Stack Overflow planning to remove that link? I am using it because it is shorter and easier to type in than the new link (mcve vs minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Just use `[mre]`, which gets auto-expanded.

Comment: @jonrsharpe `[mcve]` and `[mvce]` also do. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments

Comment: [mvce](/help/mvce) doesn't work

Comment: @WaisKamal no, not help/mvce but *literally* the text `[mvce]`. It's called a magic link and it gets automatically turned into a link. EDIT: although the MSE link doesn't mention it. I'm pretty sure mvce *was* added as another alias. I personally just use mcve, though.

Comment: Trying it: [mvce]. Doesn't work. Perhaps some bug is there.

Comment: It hasn't for a while actually. Feels like it's been disabled

Comment: @WaisKamal Testing it on here does not establish whether it works on the main site.

Comment: @khelwood I've tested it on main a few times - doesn't work

Comment: @Zoe You're right. [mvce] does not work but [mcve] still does. (And [mre] does, of course.)

Comment: Relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400525/quick-reference-links-to-important-so-pages/400526#400526 Note that I wrote that answer.

Comment: As has been mentioned, you can use a variety of different "quick-links" to insert a hyperlink to the applicable page in the Help Center. However, rarely should you need to do so. If a question that needs one is missing an MCVE, then you should simply cast a vote to close the question. There is no need for a comment, unless you're giving some detailed, specific advice. The close reason will already contain a link to the Help Center, so there is no need for a comment duplicating it.

Comment: `[mvce]` was never on [the referenced page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments).

Answer (score 15):

I don't know about Stack Overflow's plans, but there's actually an easier way to put the link in a comment: [shorthand links](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting):

> `[mcve]`, `[mre]`, `[reprex]`, `[repro]`, `[example]` -- link to [/help/minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), with the link text "minimal reproducible example".

*<sup>Formatting modified</sup>*

Note that these shorthands don't work on meta. See [meta shorthands](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: Oh, thank you.  I realize that we aren't supposed to say "thank you", but "thank you" (and an up-vote).  I've known about `[mcve]` for a while, but your *Shorthand Links* link is a marvelous thing.

Comment: Bah, no [`[sscce]`](http://sscce.org/)? :)