# Quick link to AI policy in comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, magic-links

I often type `[mcve]` or `[edit]` in comments to generate a [quick link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/400526/1997232).

But what about the recent AI policy? There is [help/ai-policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy), but neither `[ai-policy]` nor `[help/ai-policy]` work.

Comment: Apparently it's frowned upon to accuse an answerer of using AI, according to [What should I do if I suspect that a question or answer is written by ChatGPT?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421988/what-should-i-do-if-i-suspect-that-a-question-or-answer-is-written-by-chatgpt), even if it's painfully obvious (it usually is). I stopped trying to have a rational discussion it in the comments and just downvote and raise a flag. Nonetheless +1 for sentiment, because AI spam answering is still a huge problem on the site from my experience (although somewhat better than it was half year ago).

Comment: @ggorlen: Have any of your recent genAI flags been acted on?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I've been raising fewer of them and monitoring them less, but it seems so. in the old days (~July 2023) flags were quite backlogged and took weeks to be handled, but I think it's sped up since then since the AI banner introduction and moderators strike over.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk They are being handled, but not as promptly. So you may have some that will be handled the same day, while at the same time some still pending from the last July. I think there is still a huge backlog of AI flags.

Answer (score 11):

A workaround for the moment is using relative URLs:

```markdown
[link text](/help/ai-policy)
```

Which produces:
[link text](/help/ai-policy)

The link will go to `<base domain><relative link in the markdown>` or:

- for Meta Stack Overflow: `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy` (the Meta link will redirect to the main Help Center pages)
- for Main Stack Overflow: `https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy`

Comment: Testing: [/conduct](/conduct), [/help/why-vote](/help/why-vote), [/help/how-to-answer](/help/how-to-answer). Cool, didn't know about *relative* links. They are not as short, but *shorter* than normal links, thanks!